# How to configure Jasmin SMS Gateway with SSL Certificate?

Tags: ssl, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

I want to configure my **Jasmin SMS gateway** so that I can use it with a third party application, So I need to, solely, enable the gateway API with SSL. But I can't find a valid Documentation on **how to deploy a Globally Signed SSL Certificate to Jasmin SMS Gateway API**. Can anyone help me?

Comment: WHat about proxy the connection to the API with apache, nginx, haproxy which can terminate the SSL connetion?

Comment: Sounds a good Idea, gonna try it and post the answer if worked